# Asymptotic form of solution to biased random walk

Tags: approximations, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, randomness, asymptotics

([Cross post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4887202/) from math.stackexchange)

Consider a continuous time biased random walk on a 1D lattice. The random walker walks with rate $k_\mathrm{R}$ to the right and with rate $k_\mathrm{L}$ to the left. The probability $p_n(t)$ of being at location $n$ at time $t$ is then described by
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}p_n(t)=k_\mathrm{R}p_{n-1}(t)+k_\mathrm{L}p_{n+1}(t)-(k_\mathrm{L}+k_\mathrm{R})p_n(t).$$
The solution of this equation is
$$p_n(t)=\left(\frac{k_\mathrm{R}}{k_\mathrm{L}}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}I_n(2\sqrt{k_\mathrm{L}k_\mathrm{R}}t)\mathrm{e}^{-(k_\mathrm{L}+k_\mathrm{R})t},$$
where $I_n(t)$ is the Bessel function.

On the other hand, since this process is related to drift diffusion, we expect the long time limit $t\to\infty$ to be given by
$$p_n(t)\sim\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi Dt}}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{(n-vt)^2}{4Dt}},$$
with the "diffusion constant" $D=(k_\mathrm{L}+k_\mathrm{R})/2$ and "drift velocity" $v=k_\mathrm{R}-k_\mathrm{L}$. Visually, this also seems to be correct for all values I tried. Is it possible to derive the asymptotic limit from our expression of $$p_n(t)=\left(\frac{k_\mathrm{R}}{k_\mathrm{L}}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}I_n(2\sqrt{k_\mathrm{L}k_\mathrm{R}}t)\mathrm{e}^{-(k_\mathrm{L}+k_\mathrm{R})t}~?$$

I have already tried using the integral representation of the Bessel function and applying the saddle-point approximation to it, but this does not give the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

This is not directly answering the OP question, but might be helpful. The diffusion limit appears more naturally if you give a physical meaning to the jumps $n\to n\pm1$. For example, consider that the walker can occupy the edges of a lattice. The integer $n$ labels the edge at position $x_n$ and the separation between edges is $\Delta x$. Let me rewrite the master equation in terms of $x_n$ and $\Delta x$,
$$\partial_x p(x_n,t)=k_\mathrm{R}p(x_n-\Delta x,t)+k_\mathrm{L}p(x_n+\Delta x,t)-(k_\mathrm{L}+k_\mathrm{R})p(x_n,t).$$
Now it is easy to show that in the continuous limit $\Delta x\to 0$, $x_n\to x$,  the master equation becomes a Fokker-Planck equation (neglecting contributions of order $\mathcal{O}((\Delta x)^3)$,
$$\partial_x p(x,t)=-v\partial_xp(x,t)+D\partial_x^2 p(x,t).$$
with $v=(k_R-k_L)\Delta x$ and $D = (k_R+k_L)(\Delta x)^2$.

The above Fokker-Planck equation has the Gaussian solution that you wrote. The constants have extra $\Delta x$ factors that account for the proper dimensions of a velocity and a diffusion constant.

These things are nicely discussed in the first chapter of the book  ["A Kinetic View of Statistical Physics"](https://books.google.es/books?hl=es&lr=&id=cc3pApnX3kYC&oi=fnd&pg=PR7&dq=non-equilibrium%20redner&ots=JM5g9v6dUp&sig=_QC8_yVvgQ5BnvNEO9sDpWB4muQ#v=onepage&q=non-equilibrium%20redner&f=false).